# Is there a replacement to the Layout Page app ?

Tags: appexchange

The Layout Page app (by Clerisoft) is an app which could automatically convert any Page Layout into a Visualforce page. Apparently, this has now been discontinued just recently.

Does anybody know if there is an app which can serve as a replacement ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

doing a web search, just found this

http://visualforce-generator.herokuapp.com/

Answer (score 1):

@michael - I forgot I had posted here. I installed this : http://forceguru.blogspot.com/2011/06/visualforce-code-generator.html  ; Yours looks good too. Thanks !